# Is there a way to make the browser take into account actual element width when choosing an image from srcset?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to set the optimal size of the image in the element, which is dynamically sizes.
Here is an example code:

```
<div style="max-width:500px">
    <img 
        style="width:100%;" 
        src="default-path.jpg" 
        srcset="image-200px.jpg 200w, image-250px.jpg 250w, image-300px.jpg 300w, image-400px.jpg 400w, image-500px.jpg 500w"  
    />
</div>
```

The issue here is that the parent element's width is calculated dynamically by the browser, based on the available width in it's parent element. It can be anything from 0 to 500px.
The srcset attribute works by taking the browser's viewport width and selecting the best image based on theviewport width.
What I would like to achieve here is that the browser would take the best image based on the width of the current  element.
For example, if the element is 380px wide, it should take the image-400px.jpg as the source for the  element.

As far as I researched this issue, there doesn't seem to be a way to achieve this with pure HTML or CSS.
The only possible solution I see is to make a JavaScript change the srcset of the element once it gets rendered, however I would like to avoid adding additional JavaScript logic for this task.
It seems that the srcset attribute is meant to use the viewport or screen width so it can download the correct image before it starts rendering the element.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are the @media rules for css. (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Basically, you can specify any paramenter you want to change within the css if you pass in a @media condition. The example below only applies the values if the screenwidth is >= 600px.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
#Your values here
}
```

You could add a picture with sourceset. To show you that I added an inline solution.

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="extralarge.jpg" media="(min-width: 1000px)">
  <source srcset="large.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">
  <source srcset="medium.jpg" media="(min-width: 600px)">
  <img srcset="small.jpg" alt="…">
</picture>
```

I also found this article might be helpful for you: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/
There are different techniques how responsive images can be created.